# I can't create react app after updating node js v.15.0

Tags: reactjs

```
C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Template Project>npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL
npm ERR! Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-21T10_03_45_137Z-debug.log
```

Comment: please explain problem correctly.

Comment: use Long Term Support (LTS) version.

Comment: got the same error.
Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:ReactJsApp rahul$ npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL: Protocol \"https:\" not supported. Expected \"http:\"
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL
npm ERR! Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rahul/.npm/_logs/2020-11-01T08_20_05_490Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Resolved by downgrading node@15 to node@14.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`unset http_proxy; unset https_proxy; unset all_proxy;`

then

`npm install` again